# Can't install Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle, spree

trying to install Spree on Ubuntu, but I'm new to Linux systems. Below is the error message:

```
-desktop ~/mystore $ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
  In Gemfile:
    spree (~> 3.1.1) was resolved to 3.1.1, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.1.1)
    spree (~> 3.1.1) was resolved to 3.1.1, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.1.1)
    spree (~> 3.1.1) was resolved to 3.1.1, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.1.1)
    spree (~> 3.1.1) was resolved to 3.1.1, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.1.1)
    spree (~> 3.1.1) was resolved to 3.1.1, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.1.1)
    spree_gateway (~> 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      spree_core (~> 3.0.0)
```

And all this gems is installed, below is the list:

```
 rails (5.0.0.1, 4.2.7.1, 4.2.6, 4.2.5)
    rails-deprecated_sanitizer (1.0.3)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.1, 1.0.7)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
    railties (5.0.0.1, 4.2.7.1, 4.2.6, 4.2.5)
    rake (11.3.0, 10.4.2)
    ransack (1.4.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.9.8)
    rb-inotify (0.9.7)
    rdoc (4.3.0, 4.2.1)
    responders (2.3.0)
    sass (3.4.22)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
    sdoc (0.4.2)
    select2-rails (3.5.9.1)
    sixarm_ruby_unaccent (1.1.1)
    spree (3.1.1, 3.0.0)
    spree_api (3.1.1, 3.0.0)
    spree_auth_devise (3.1.0)
    spree_backend (3.1.1, 3.0.0)
    spree_cmd (3.1.1, 3.0.0)
    spree_core (3.1.1, 3.0.0)
    spree_frontend (3.1.1, 3.0.0)
    spree_gateway (3.1.0, 3.0.0)
    spree_sample (3.1.1, 3.0.0)
```

I tried to install different version of rails, Spree, but always the same error.
Could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install spree with ~> 3.1.1 and spree_gateway '~> 3.0.0'.

This can be a dependency problem

Alternative option is

```
 gem 'spree'
 gem 'spree_gateway'
```

Put gem without specifying version

Execute:

```
 bundle install
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install spree with `~> 3.1.1` and spree_gateway `'~> 3.0.0'`. You have to change in your Gemfile spree_gateway version. 
Try

```
gem 'spree', '~> 3.1.1'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.1.0'
```

Comment: I changed in Gemfile according your comment amd still have issue:    spree_auth_devise (~> 3.0.5) was resolved to 3.0.5, which depends on
      spree_core (~> 3.0.0)

    spree_gateway (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
      spree_core (~> 3.1.0.beta)spree_gateway (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
      spree_core (~> 3.1.0.beta)

Comment: then its the exact same problem, except with spree_auth_devise instead of spree_gateway. You need the same version of all of the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

So I fallowed all your recommendations - removed versions from gemfile, removed all spree* excluding v3.0.0, only auth_devise is v3.1.0. Version of auth_devise 3.0.0 doesn't exist in repository I installed spree v3.1.0 for all the gem's to be the same version. Stil doesn't works A, below is the result:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_core":
  In Gemfile:
    spree (~> 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.0.0)

    spree (~> 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.0.0)

    spree (~> 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.0.0)

    spree (~> 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.0.0)

    spree (~> 3.0.0) was resolved to 3.0.0, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.0.0)

    spree_gateway (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
      spree_core (~> 3.1.0.beta)
```

Bundle update returns me this:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (>= 5.0.0.1, ~> 5.0.0)

    spree (~> 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
      spree_core (= 3.1.0) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
       rails (~> 4.2.6)
```

Answer (score 0):

For now spree is not available for rails 5.0, so if you want to use it, you must go for rails 4.2.6(at least)

To create a project using an older version of rails just type: rails 4.2.6 new MyAppName

You can try this If works then fine otherwise use older version, as follow in the spree's README:

```
gem 'spree', github: 'spree/spree'

gem 'spree_auth_devise', github: 'spree/spree_auth_devise'

gem 'spree_gateway', github: 'spree/spree_gateway'
```